# Best way to update a live database while persisting data?

Tags: database, sql-server-ce

In short; I have created a small WinForms application for a friend.

Whilst my friend was using the application I decided to make changes to the application. In doing so I added a few columns to tables within the database.

I now want to implement that changes, what is the best way to get his database up to date with all the new columns whilst keeping his data intact?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
ALTER TABLE ADD NewColumn nvarchar(50) NULL
```

and run the required statements using SqlCeCmd.ExecuteNonQuery